# How to auto-update a website mirror with exceptions to certain pages?

Tags: script, automation, website, updates, mirroring

I'm currently mirroring a website on my server. The site itself is rarely updated, but it is updated enough that info can become outdated quickly.

I mirrored it first with wget, and this worked fine, but I made some changes:

- The original index.html used frames, but the site also provides a main.html which is essentially index.html but without frames. I deleted index.html and renamed main.html.
- I did not want to mirror the webchat, blog or forum, so I deleted those files and directories and made directories "blogs" "forum" and "chat" and placed a php redirect in each of those, redirecting visitors to the orignal site.

I'd like to auto-update the mirror (maybe once every 24-72 hours), but preserve the changes I made. Is this possible? How would I go about doing it? I am completely clueless as to how.

Thanks for any and all help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `wget --miror`. Possible solutions:

1. If the sections to be preserved are in directories this may work:

   `wget --exclude-directories=LIST`
2. If you can tolerate it you allow the race condition you can let wget overwrite things and then overwrite them back with a script that restores them.
3. Prevent overwriting of the files you don't want to change.

   `chmod 444 index.html`